# Python Dataframe - Using Groupby to Send Individual Values from One Column Based off Another Column's Values to Function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as exemplified below:

```
id buyer  breakeven  training   rfm_id
1   yes     0.04         1        123
2   no      0.02         1        325
3   yes     0.06         0        512
4   yes     0.03         0        422
5   no      0.1          1        142
```

And I am trying to pass the data from the dataset into the following functions:

```
def rate(x, lev="yes"):
    return np.nanmean(x == lev)

def sendto(x, lev="yes", breakeven=0):
    return rate(x, lev) > breakeven 

sendto_break = df[df["training"]==1].groupby("rfm_id").buyer.agg(sendto, breakeven = df["breakeven"])
```

However, I keep receiving an error that states "ValueError: Must produce aggregated value". I understand this is because the code is set up in a way where the groupby is sending the data piece by piece (by rfm_id) while also simultaneously trying to send the entire breakeven column. I need to be able to also send the breakeven column piece by piece (ie send 0.04 for rfm 123 and then 0.02 for rfm 325) but I cannot figure out how. I tried using a loop and iloc/loc, but none of these approaches worked for me. I also saw other examples like the one below, but it also didn't work.

```
df.loc[df["rfm_id"] == "rfm_id", "breakeven"]
```

Is there an efficient way I can do this?

Thank you!

Edit: I am hoping the output is as such:

```
rfm_id   sendto_output
   123      True
   325      False
   512      True
   422      True
   142      False
```

Where the sendto function returns true/false based on comparing the df["breakeven"] result to the rate calculated in the rate function.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I am looking to create a new dataframe ("sendto_break") with rfm_id and the output of the "sendto" function.

Comment: Will you please add a sample dataframe containing your expected output, @gardencode?

Comment: Edited to add a sample of my expected output, I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`agg` needs to aggregate, so to return a single value per group. However, in `sendto` you perform a comparison of a scalar to `df['breakeven']`, which broadcasts the output to a Series.

The exact computation you expect is not entirely clear, so I can't directly provide code. Yet, what you should probably do it to aggregate with `rate` and then compare to breakeven.